# Adding word boundaries regex pattern varying over loop?

Tags: python, regex

My code looks like this.

```
for userinput in sys.argv[1:]:
    pattern = re.compile(userinput, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
    if re.search(pattern, string):
        do action
```

I want to search through a string of text using this pattern but exclude the cases where the pattern exists in between a different word, such as 'hi' inside 'which'. So I tried putting the word boundary

```
pattern = re.compile('\buserinput\b', flags = re.IGNORECASE)
```

but I realized this will search the literal string 'userinput'. How do I add word boundaries to the patterns that change over the loop?

Comment: `'\b'` is a backspace, not a word boundary. `r'\b'` is a word boundary. You want to use a variable in a regex, so use `rf'\b{userinput}\b'` or alternatives.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks!! that works. Didn't know f string can be used in the regex functions

Comment: Well, a regex is a piece of text, a string of characters. Surely f-strings can be used in regex functions. A more important thing though is to select the right boundary.